# Sine to bipolar sine

Tags: operational-amplifier

I have a circuit that outputs a positive sine wave with an amplitude from ~0.6V to 0V. The peak values can vary from 0.6V down to 0V. An example of two possible waveforms are shown in the image below:

[image]

I need a way to convert this varying sine wave to a bipolar signal:

[image]

This would be trivial for a constant sine amplitude, as I could add in an offset, but I'm having trouble developing a circuit for a range of amplitudes. I am currently toying around with a peak-detector and using that as the offset. I am interested to hear any other takes on the problem.

Comment: DC-block capacitor. EZ PZ.

Comment: And this is why I posted here... I knew there was something simple I was missing. Thank you!

Comment: RC high pass filter will work, however note that when the amplitude changes (including start-up) you'll get a transient with the RC time constant. Size will depend on when in the cycle it changes. Maybe that's not a problem in your application.

Answer (score 11):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fVJyJ2.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Choose C1 and R1 to suit the lowest sinewave frequency. Choose R1 so that it doesn't load up the signal source (connected to the input port) excessively.

Answer (score 6):

One way to think about this is that you have a high frequency (that you want) and a low frequency (that you do not want).  *DC is the ultimate in low frequency.*

So, how do you separate a high frequency from a low frequency?  A **high pass filter!**  The simplest of which is a series capacitor.  Knowing that you have a DC-offset, this capacitor is also called a DC blocking capacitor, as mentioned in the comments.

Below, C1 is the most basic implementation of the circuit.  It *relies* on the output circuit's impedance to allow the AC signal to center itself.  If that impedance is too high, then adding a resistor (R1) like in the second circuit will allow the current to flow back and forth in the capacitor, allowing it to equalize.  The exact values of the cap and resistor will depend on the frequency of the signal and the impedances of both the input and the output.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9zz5X.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Circuit 1 is not a filter by itself, but usually there is a resistance somewhere in the output, which makes it actually circuit 2.

Comment: @user253751 circuit one **relies** on the output circuit's impedance, while circuit two provides said impedance.  I'll update the post to make it more clear.

Comment: Actually circuit 1 relies on the INPUT impedance of whetever reads this sine wave to filter out the waveform. Not only it's generally too high to just happen to be the rolloff frequency you want, but it's also undetermined before testing and varies from chip to chip.

Comment: @MisterMystère The input impedance of the circuit that reads it == the output circuit's impedance.  I included the appropriate apostrophe to show possession.  I'm not sure how to make that more clear.

Comment: I wasn't talking about the apostrophe but about the "output" terminology - not important enough to argue, but was worth commenting.